# on a dry and barren run -- what does that mean?

Tags: meaning

From the song "[I Am Australian](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/seekers/iamaustralian.html)" by the Australian pop group *The Seekers*.

> I came upon the prison ship
>   Bowed down by iron chains
>   I fought the land
>   Endured the lash
>   And waited for the rains
>   I'm a settler
>   I'm a farmer's wife
>   **On a dry and barren run**
>   A convict then a free man
>   I became Australian

What kind of run are they talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Run* here is probably a "sheep run"; the online [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/sheep-run) gives the definition

> (Especially in Australia) an extensive tract of land on which sheep are pastured.

A 'dry and barren run' would be a farm where survival would be very difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Pop music often takes liberties with use of language. I believe what they really meant was, "On a run through a dry and barren place." However, like many songs, there is room for other interpretations as well.

Comment: I think it means run as in landscape kind of run